# Business rules implementation in MVC

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller

So after my first question about MVC and some answers from esteemed stackoverflow memebrs, I read a few books about MVC especially by Scott Alen.

My question is that how do we implement show/hide controls, disable/enable controls based on user selection and particular value of field?

Do we create seperate view for each case? In ASP.Net form and codebehind we could write as much logic as we wanted.

Hope this example could clarify

1. My business spec says if Carier is UnitedHealth then show 'diagnosis code field' but hide it when Carrier is BlueCross.
2. Another example is, if user selects a particular value in listbox, hide certain fields.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend doing this through databinding. You can add visibility properties to your model that are backed by the logic you describe. During rendering the visibility properties will hide/show the elements in question.

Comment: Thanks TGH. How do I handle 2nd case, like user interaction. Unobtrusive Javascript and Jquery are there to help, but not sure if that is right path.

Comment: It really depends on the scenario. Simple cases can be done client side. However, other cases might warent a get request to reload the page.